# Какой код лучше использовать для  не авторизованных пользователей

Tags: php, mysql

Какой код лучше использовать для  не авторизованных пользователей?

**1 код**

```
       $res_login = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM `datacenter` WHERE `login` = "'.$_POST['login'].'"' );
      if (mysql_num_rows($res_login) != 1){
echo '<script>location.replace("nologin.php");</script>'; exit;
}
```

**2 код**

```
  session_start();
   $a = $_SESSION['login'];   
   if ($a ! = null ){
echo '<script>location.replace("nologin.php");</script>'; exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенаправление лучше делать так:

```
    header("Location: nologin.php");
    exit;
```

P.S: Нужно контролировать, что-бы перед этим не было никакого вывода ( `echo, print, print_r` )

А между способами - по идеи, с сессией будет быстрее ( но страдает когерентность - пользователя удалили, а его сессия ещё жива )

P.S Сессию и cookie можно украсть, об этом стоит заботится в любом случае

Comment: добавлю на всякий случай - выводом может быть так-же пробельный символ до открывающегося php тега **<?**

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не тот не другой не использовал, без ява скрипт они не будут перенаправлять куда надо ...

Comment: так <script>location.replace("nologin.php");</script>
это яваскипт

Comment: Я не совсем ясно выразился, если в браузере отключена поддержка яваскрипт(или еще по каким-то причинам не работает) то ни первое ни второе не сработает, если можно обойтись без яваскрипт то следует так и сделать, а здесь можно ... Я бы дал совет по этому поводу, но вплотную не касался написания системы регистрации/авторизации, но если бы я начал писать - я бы на стороне сервера генерировал для незарегистрированных пользователей отдельный HTML ... Или перенаправлял бы их на другиие страницы есть масса способов для этого кроме javascript...